# Erro ao gerar o APK no ionic 3

Tags: ionic, apk

Estou com o seguinte erro quando dou o seguinte comando: ionic cordova build android. Alguem pode me ajudar? Qual a solução?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:215)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61) (node:1616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
```

Comment: Parece algum problema com o gradle. Tente abrir o projeto no android studio pra ver se encontra algum erro de compilacao.

Comment: Concordo com nosso amigo @RaphaelStefani, caso não funcione tente remover o plugin da plataforma Android:
ionic cordova platform rm android
e reinstale na ultima versão:
ionic cordova platform add android

Tive um problema parecido e resolveu para mim.